# How to change a convolution neural network for a regression problem

Tags: regression, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, graph-neural-network

I haved downloaded a Graph convolution neural network (GCNN) code from the github, on which the authors extend the traditional CNN to graph data and implement a user-defined convolution/pooling layer, see [github](https://github.com/tkipf/gcn) ).

I would like to use this model on my problem, but this code is implemented as a classifier. How should I change it for a regression problem?

Comment: replace the softmax layer with a linear activation? obviously pick an appropriate loss function to go along with it.

Comment: @shimao, thanks for your reply. Are you suggesting only two changes are sufficient ? 1) replace the last softmax layer with a linear activation layer. 2) change the loss function to mean squared error. I was wondering how can I get 1-dimension result?

Comment: @ice_lin Were your input data defined on the same graph or you had to define a new adjacency matrix for input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what possible values your regression can take, but likely you want to change the activation of the final layer from what it is now (likely softmax or sigmoid) to linear (no activation function).

(I say it depends because if your values are non-negative, you could use ReLU, if they are bounded on both sides you may consider using a scaled sigmoid or tang, etc.)

You will also need to update the loss function. It is likely cross entropy, usually RMSE is what you want for regressions.